# Create table from csv tree file using python

Tags: python, parsing, tree

I have csv file that looks to have the structure of a tree (the file has 3000 lines)

```
A,
,B
,,B1
,,B2
,,,,,B2a
,C
,,C1
,,,C1a
,,C2
,,,,,C2a1a
```

I would like parse file to obtaining a table that looks like this

```
Parent Child
A B
B B1
B B2
B2 B2a
A C
C C1
C1 C1a
C C2
C2 C2a1a
```

Note the leaf with values B2a and C2a1a has more commas but is related to the closest father

Comment: what have you tried? show your code

Answer (score 0):

you can try `yaml`

```py
import yaml
import re
import io

s = """A,
,B
,,B1
,,B2
,,,,,B2a
,C
,,C1
,,,C1a
,,C2
,,,,,C2a1a"""

s_ = re.sub(r'(,*[\w\d]+)', r'\1:', s)
parsed = yaml.load(io.StringIO(s_.replace(',', ' ')))

def flatten_and_print(d):
  for k,v in d.items():
    if (isinstance(v, dict)):
      for k2 in v:
        print(k, k2)
      flatten_and_print(v)

flatten_and_print(parsed)

# A B
# A C
# B B1
# B B2
# B2 B2a
# C C1
# C C2
# C1 C1a
# C2 C2a1a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stack for this, which maintains the path from the root to the currently node from the input.

As apparently the number of commas can increase with more than 1, the stack should include the depth of each element it stores.

Here is an implementation:

```
def pairs(csv):
    stack = []
    for line in csv.splitlines():
        name = line.lstrip(",")
        depth = len(line) - len(name)
        name = name.rstrip(",")
        while stack and depth <= stack[-1][0]:
            stack.pop()
        if stack:
            yield stack[-1][1], name
        stack.append((depth, name))
```

Here is how you could call it:

```
csv = """A,
,B
,,B1
,,B2
,,,,,B2a
,C
,,C1
,,,C1a
,,C2
,,,,,C2a1a"""

for pair in pairs(csv):
    print(*pair)
```